# Ajuda com pesquisa com Data e Hora

Tags: java, android

Bom Dia

Estou fazendo uma pesquisa por data no android e estou tendo problema na hora de verificar a hora.ele fala que deu erro de sintaxe proximo a hora, e outra quando pego a data  a hora está mostrando menos 3 horas. alguem pode me ajudar?  segue o código  o formato da hora que eu pego no banco é este: 2016-11-23 16:34:37.000

```
public String nomeTabela()  {
    String Pesquisa = "";
    ConexaoDao conexao = new ConexaoDao();
    ObjetoConexao objConexao = new ObjetoConexao();
    objConexao.db_connect_string = "flexvale.hopto.org:1433";
    objConexao.db_name = "FlexPortaCom";
    objConexao.db_userid = "sa";
    objConexao.db_password = "flextelecom";
    Connection conn = conexao.dbConnect(objConexao);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date () );
    System.out.println(currentDateandTime);

    if (conn == null) {

        Pesquisa = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";

    } else



    if (conn != null) try {


        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

        String queryString =  " Select SUM(DIFERENÇA)as somaMes from TOTALIZADOR WHERE  NID = 252 and DATAHORA  >= "+currentDateandTime+" and DATAHORA = "+currentDateandTime+" ";
        ResultSet rs;



        rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);

        if (rs.next()) {

            Pesquisa = rs.getString("somaMes");

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Pesquisa = e.getMessage();


    }
    return Pesquisa ;




}
```

Comment: Coloca o erro exato na sua pergunta

Comment: Sorack  quando eu faço a pesquisa sem a data por exemplo 2016-11-23 vai dar certo a pesquisa  mas quando eu coloco  2016-11-23 16:34:37.000    a pesquisa retorna erro de sintaxe próximo a 16. que é o inicio das horas. eu preciso das horas porque preciso fazer várias pesquisas,  retornando dados dos ultimos 10 minutos, 1 hora, etc

Comment: Qual é o formato do campo **DATAHORA** na tabela ?

Comment: Thiago o formato é este - 2016-11-23 16:34:37.000    quando eu faço a pesquisa sem as horas  ele me retorna vazio mesmo tendo dados e quando coloco a horas ele da um erro de sintaxe próximo ao iinico das horas.

Comment: o campo é datetime

Comment: e esta é a minha pesquisa, preciso pegar o somatório do campo deiferença entre as datas   " Select SUM(DIFERENÇA)as somaMes from TOTALIZADOR WHERE NID = 253 and DATAHORA  BETWEEN  "+Data1+" and "+Data2+" ";

Answer (score 1):

Ainda que seja possível executar uma consulta SQL usando concatenação de texto, não o faça, pois está colocando seu sistema em risco ao permitir injeção de SQL.

Use um [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) e passe os parâmetros de data usando o método [`setDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,%20java.sql.Date)).

[Exemplo](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-insert-date-value-in-preparedstatement/):

```
private static java.sql.Date getCurrentDate() {
    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    return new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
}

public String nomeTabela()  {

    ...

    String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
        + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
        + "(?,?,?,?)";
    preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);    
    preparedStatement.setDate(4, getCurrentDate());

    ...

}
```

Nota: se quiser mesmo concatenar uma data literal, o primeiro passo é colocar aspas ao antes e depois, afinal há um espaço entre a data e a hora. De todos os bancos que conheço, alguns aceitam um literal de texto e fazem a conversão implícita para uma data. Porém, neste caso provavelmente você vai precisar usar uma [função para converter explicitamente a string para data/hora](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).